# getJavaScriptResult devuelve null

Tags: javascript, java, web, script

Estoy tratando de loguearme en una web y recuperar una página de un producto concreta. Mi código Java es el siguiente:

```
        String log = page.executeJavaScript(
            "document.getElementById(\"form_postalcode\").innerHTML = \"<select id='cl_postal_code' class='postalCodesSelect form-control form_field select2-hidden-accessible' data-validation-engine='validate[required]' title='' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placeholder='Código Postal' tabindex='-1' data-original-title='Por favor, selecciona un código postal' aria-hidden='true'><option></option><option value='05289'>05289</option><option value='05520'>05520</option><option value='15001'>15001</option><option value='15002'>15002</option></select><span class='select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--above select2-container--open' dir='ltr' style='width: 210px;'><span class='selection'><span class='select2-selection select2-selection--single' role='combobox' aria-autocomplete='list' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='true' title='' tabindex='5' aria-labelledby='select2-cl_postal_code-container' data-toggle='tooltip' data-original-title='Por favor, selecciona un código postal' aria-owns='select2-cl_postal_code-results'><span class='select2-selection__rendered' id='select2-cl_postal_code-container' aria-label='NUEVO CLIENTE. Por favor, selecciona un código postal' title='15002'>15002</span><span class='select2-selection__arrow' role='presentation'><b role='presentation'></b></span></span></span><span class='dropdown-wrapper' aria-hidden='true'></span></span>\";" + 
            "document.getElementById(\"cl_postal_code\").value = \"15002\";" +
            "$('.btn_new_client').click(); " +
            "window.open('https://www.miweb.com/producto/?productID=6007020','_self');"+
            "$('.price').text();").getJavaScriptResult().toString();
```

El código javascript lo que hace es setear un valor de código postal, en este caso '15002' y enviar el formulario. A continuación carga la página de un producto y devuelve el precio de ese producto, pero en getJavaScriptResult() me devuelve nulo, a qué se debe? Teniendo en cuenta que ese código javascript me devuelve valor para la última línea al probarlo a ejecutar sobre la consola javascript del navegador.

Comment: Hola. Si, he probado a ejecutar ese javascript directamente sobre la web y no da ningún error. La línea $('.price').text(); devuelve valor en la consola de javascript del navegador.

Comment: Tienes una errata: `"window.open('https://www.miweb.com/producto/?productID=6007020','_self\');"`. Fíjate que tras `_self`estás escapando una comilla simple, quitando el `\ ` debería funcionar

Comment: @rencinas No es duplicada, el OP tiene claro dónde se obtiene el null, pero no entiende el por qué del comportamiento.

Comment: Hola. Error mío al escribirlo. Edito la pregunta pero sigue dando null corrigiendo eso. Creo que carga la nueva página que le indico, o por lo menos lo intenta,  y reinicia el javascript por eso no me devuelve nada.